# How to set PUBLIC_URL back to the server root for npm run build

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I made a simple react app, and wanted to deploy it.

At first, I tried `npm run build`. I got "The project was built assuming it is hosted at **the server root**."

I needed to deploy the app to my web server, so found a solution that worked:
`set PUBLIC_URL=http://example.com/sampleDir&&npm run build`

However, the next time I type `npm run build`, the message is always `The project was built assuming it is hosted at` "*whatever path I set just before*".

I tried `set PUBLIC_URL='root'` to set back to the original condition. But the message I got after executing `npm run build` was not the same as the first time.

Rather it said: "The project was built assuming it is hosted at **root/**."

If anyone knows, please let me know how to return this situation to the original: "The project was built assuming it is hosted at **the server root**."

Answer (score 0):

1.

Unfortunately, my command line does not recognize 'unset':

```
'unset' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

(it seems that your way should work fine, and other google searches support it... I'll have to search more about it later)

Fortunately, though, the next line worked:

```
set PUBLIC_URL=&&npm run build
```

I'm not sure why... probably because I'm using cmder as my command line???

2.
Your package.json advice was tried, too.
My original package.json was like below:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

And, I changed it into yours:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "build:sample": "PUBLIC_URL=http://example.com/sampleDir npm run build"
  }
```

Then, I got an error message... (I'm not sure what this error exactly means...)

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\MyLocalDevFolder\scripts\build.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Anyway, after more searches, I could do what I want without contaminating the environment, adding the code below after the original "scripts" property in the package.json:

```
  "homepage": "http://example.com/sampleDir/",
```

Thank you again for your advice, Tholle~
Happy coding~~~